# Why is my docker build command failing

Tags: macos, docker, unix, opencl, dockerfile

I have docker installed on my macbook pro OS Sierra 16G1212

I have a simple docker file in /mypath/Dockerfile

When I try the command:

```
docker build .
```

I get an error:

> error checking context: 'can't stat '/Users/bdisha/Library/Caches/com.cisco.Jabber/com.apple.opencl''.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by me creating a "dockerfiles" directory and moving my Dockerfile in there.
After that, I could manage to build the image just fine.